# Custom fact in Ansible without [section]

Tags: ansible

I have these custom fact files:

```
% cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/bar.fact
bar='x'
% cat /etc/ansible/facts.d/foo.fact
[foo]
foo='baz'
```

Then I execute this command:

```
% ansible -m setup localhost -a filter=ansible_local
```

Which produces this output:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {
            "bar": "error loading fact - please check content",
            "foo": {
                "foo": {
                    "foo": "'baz'"
                }
            }
        },
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

How can I craft a fact file that will result in this output?

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {
            "bar": "'x'",
         ... omitted for brevity ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSON fact file instead of INI. INI files have a strict hierarchical structure of sections with name/value pairs, so there will always be two levels of nesting from the file itself underneath the top-level key that is determined by the file name. JSON is more flexible because it can represent more varied structures and the parsed JSON is assigned directly to the top-level key.

In this case you would put a single JSON string in a file named `/etc/ansible/facts.d/bar.fact`:

```
"'x'"
```

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_local.bar": "'x'"
}
```